# Use anonyous function in object for more than one task

Tags: javascript

I've got an Object "region" (will be different regions in the world), and I'm going to have an array of them with various properties that I apply.

I'd like the list of objects to contain the code to do various things like normalise the internal data, and add weights.

Here i have TTT (total travel time), TJL (total journey length) and PeaceIndex (how dangerous somewhere is) as properties.

Once I have the whole list I'm going to rank them against each other normalised to start with.

```
function region(TTT, TJL, peaceIndex) {

    var n = function (TTTtopvalue,TTTbottomvalue,TTT) {

        var colVal = parseFloat(TTT);
        var numerator = colVal - TTTbottomvalue;  //Once you have the extremes 33, 55, 56, 77 e.g. 33 and 77 then (value-min)/(max-min)  55-33=22/77-33= 22/50 = .4 whatever
        var denominator = TTTtopvalue - TTTbottomvalue;
        var result = numerator/denominator

        this.TTTnormal =result ;
    }

    this.TTT = TTT;
    this.TJL = TJL;
    this.TTTnormal = 0;
    this.TTTtopvalue = 0;
    this.TTTbottomvalue = 0;
    this.peaceIndex = peaceIndex;
    this.normaliseTTT = n;
}
    var r1 = new region(45, 33, 50);
    var r2 = new region(40, 30, 55);
    var r3 = new region(333, 100, 1);

    var testArray = [r1, r2, r3];

   console.log(JSON.stringify(testArray));

   testArray[0].TTTtopvalue = 333;
   testArray[0].TTTbottomvalue = 40;
   testArray[0].normaliseTTT(333,40,45);   //this works for TTT!!

   console.log(JSON.stringify(testArray));

    testArray.sort(function(a, b){
     return a.TTT-b.TTT
    })

   console.log(JSON.stringify(testArray));
```

Now that works great for the TTT column.  However it is the same code for the TJL and peaceIndex columns.

I just can't seem to get that anonymous function to return the normalised value to the other properties.

How can I do this?

So the prototype would be

```
function (topvalue,bottomvalue,TTT or TJL or peaceIndex)
```

Save typing the thing out each time

Comment: Pass the property name to handle as a string, and use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) within `normalise` function to refer to a correct property, like `this[passed_property_name] = result;`.

Comment: @teemu can you expand on this.  I need to pass the property_name to the anonymous function -  how?

Comment: I think I got it.  this[prop_name] = result; in my function and calls with  testArray[0].normalise(333,40,45,'TTT');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separation of concerns is the answer. You need a separate class that represents a normalized value.

```
function NormalizedValue(value, top, bottom) {
    this.init(value, top, bottom);
}
NormalizedValue.prototype.init = function (value, top, bottom) {
    value = parseFloat(value);
    top = parseFloat(top);
    bottom = parseFloat(bottom);
    this.value = value;
    this.normalized = (value - bottom) / (top - bottom);
}
```

then

```
function Region(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.TTT = new NormalizedValue();
    this.TJL = new NormalizedValue();
    this.peaceIndex = new NormalizedValue();
}

var r1 = new Region("A");
var r2 = new Region("B");
var r3 = new Region("C");

r1.TTT.init(333, 40, 45);
r1.TJL.init(40, 30, 25);
r1.peaceIndex.init(1, 5, 1);
// and so on for the others...
```

and then, for example

```
testArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.TTT.normalized - b.TTT.normalized;
});
```

You can structure your `Region` constructor differently so that more of the init values can be passed as arguments, but take care that it does not get too messy (a 10-argument constructor isn't a pretty thing).

Comment: This looks nice and clean.  However I can't get it to run.  There is a brace out of position somewhere at the top.  It is bit advanced for me at the moment, can you rigigg?

Comment: My mistake, against my normal habits I haven't tested before posting my answer. Try again.

Comment: Yeah.  I like this one. I've not used the prototype.init before - but it seems easy enough, now I read up on it.  Thanks!